# C# MySQL syntax error

Tags: c#, mysql, syntax-error

I get:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near ''spectra' WHERE specId=42' at line 1**

While running this code:

```
public System.Drawing.Image GetImage(int index)
{
 using (MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
 {
  //command.CommandText = "SELECT imageObj FROM spectra WHERE specId=42"; <== Works OK!

  command.CommandText = "SELECT imageObj FROM @tname WHERE specId=@index";
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@index", index);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tname", "spectra");

  using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
  {
   if (reader.Read())
   {
    return (System.Drawing.Image)Serial.ByteArrayToObject((byte[])reader[0]);
   }
  }
 }
 return null;
}
```

I think the problems is the quotes around **spectra** . How can I remove them?

Comment: Keep in mind, you can't cast a `byte` to `byte[]`...

Comment: Irrelevant.. Function works fine when the syntax is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't replace a table name with parameters. Sadly, that is just not supported. Only parameter values in the WHERE clause can be substituted this way.

You'll have to do the substitution yourself instead of relying on the `MySqlCommand` object. Something like this should work:

```
string tableName = "spectra";
command.CommandText = 
    String.Format( "SELECT imageObj FROM {0} WHERE specId=@index", tableName );
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@index", index);
```

Comment: Works fine now.. Thanks for the fast response.